# How do make an interface for a state using generics which extend a certain object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, inheritance, interface

I have here my interface for my state.

```
export interface IState <T extends CashflowObject> {
    cashflowToPost?: T;
    cashflowList: T[];
}
```

which I want to use for my abstract class here:

```
export default abstract class CashflowListView<T> extends React.Component<{}, IState<T>>
```

I then want to specify what type of cashflowobject I will use for other classes that implement the CashflowListView class:

```
export default class AssetList extends CashflowListView<Asset>
```

Here is my object structure:

```
export interface CashflowObject {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    value: number;
    taxable: boolean;
}

export interface AssetLiability extends CashflowObject {
    interest: number;
}
export interface Liability extends AssetLiability{}
export interface Asset extends AssetLiability{}
```

However I typescript complains that in the section:

```
export default abstract class CashflowListView<T> extends React.Component<{}, IState<T>>
```

T at `React.Component<{}, IState<T>>` does not extend Cashflow object, makes sense.... but making T of type cashflow makes typescript complain in other areas like my render function in my AssetList Class:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="cashflow-table">
                {this.state.cashflowList.map((asset: Asset) => <this.AssetEntry asset={asset} />)}
                <AssetPost listUpdateFunction={this.callApi.bind(this)}></AssetPost>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

but then how would I write what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default abstract class CashflowListView<T extends CashflowObject> extends React.Component<{}, IState<T>>
```

The T in the cashflowlistview generic had to extend cashflowobject aswell. Pretty obvious now .